# Cannot start server in coldfusion builder 2

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusionbuilder

I have installed Adobe ColdFusion builder 2 and was able to set it up, using this tutorial

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/setup_dev.html

After I restarted my computer (for some updates to take effect), I am unable start the server I added using ColdFusion Builder (cfserver). I get the following error -

'starting cfusion' has encountered a problem

Ensure that the server is not already running, or another application is not using the WebServer port.

Does anyone know what to do about this? I am completely lost

EDIT: This is the error the console prints out

> > > [cfusion]:07/13 12:50:14 Error [Thread-13] - Platform, Locale, and Platform Name must not be null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Vista or Windows 7 I used to have a problem with trying to start the ColdFusion server unless I launched CFB with Administrator privileges and ran it in XP Compatability mode.